# bigquery - save large query results

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a question about saving large query results to either an external csv or to google sheets. I have a simple query that generates about 23,000 results:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT id1, id2
FROM `tableA`
WHERE A LIKE "%abcdefg%"
AND B LIKE "%some text%"
AND ts >= TIMESTAMP("2019-04-25 00:00:00")
AND ts < TIMESTAMP("2019-05-29 23:59:00")
```

I can't save more than 16,000 of these results to a csv file or output to google sheets. I want to be able to save all 23,000 results either into 1 file or into several files, but I don't know how to go about doing this. My permissions don't allow me to save the query output to a new table.

Comment: The best workaround I can think for you is to run the query for each day and download each day result to CSV file. So change this `AND ts >= TIMESTAMP("2019-04-25 00:00:00")
AND ts < TIMESTAMP("2019-05-29 23:59:00")` to this `AND ts >= TIMESTAMP("**2019-04-25** 00:00:00")
AND ts < TIMESTAMP("**2019-05-25** 23:59:00")`

Comment: you can try [Goliath](https://potensio.zendesk.com/hc/en-us) (part of [Potens.io](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/potens-io/potensio) suite of BigQuery Tools) where you will not face such limitations. Even though you will need to start with trial - but then Goliath is free to use beyond trial period. see my profile for affiliation details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Run the query as usual, then click the "Job information" tab.
2. There will be a "Destination table" entry with a link that says, "Temporary table." Click the link.
3. From this page, click "Export," then "Export to GCS."
4. Now you can export the contents of the table as CSV.